# Javascript logic to push value to array once and update the value afterwards

Tags: javascript, arrays

Could anyone suggest me a logic where i have to push data to an array once, and there after i should be updating the pushed data. If i use array.push then it appends the data each time but i just want to push data once and update it afterwards.

Comment: What are you updating...?

Comment: You can iterate through an array and check if new element already exists by some unique element field, and then, if so, you need to update that element. If no occurrence found, you need to add element

Comment: I've answered your question to the best of my understanding. In the future, please try to post any code (working or not) to demonstrate what you've tried to do.  Even if it doesn't work, it's usually a good way to determine your intent.  If your problem remains unresolved, please consider clarifying the question, possibly with code, and let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by "update"? If the same value is already in array, you just don't add it there.

Comment: An array is a series of values.  So, how would you only do `.push()` once?  This question is really not clear at all.  Please describe in words exactly what you want to happen when four successive operations happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but if you're trying to add an object to an array and update it without further appending to the array...

```
var a = [];
var data = {};
// add `data` to array `a`.
a.push(data);
// Update property `property` of `data` to value.
// This also updates `a[0]`.
data.property = 'value';
a[0].property2 = 'othervalue';
a[0].property == 'value'; // true
data.property2 == 'othervalue'; // also true
```

In short, `data` and `a[0]` refer to the same object in memory and an update to one will update the other.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code to my post. But this is what something i'm looking for... fundamentally i have a onmessage event via window.EventSource which would be sending me constant updates from the server.. those updates were JSON objects and i'm trying to add that JSON to a table row, i cannot use push because it keeps on adding the rows.. as i mentioned earlier i should append it once and update it there after..

Comment: Ok. So if you're replacing the whole object, you'd want to simply set the index `a[i] = responseJsonObject;` where `i` is the index where you initially stored / `push`ed the value.  If you're just updating fields, then you can use code similar to that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your can check if there is a value exist in array then pop data from array and push data every time in array

```
If(arr.length >= 1)
{
    arr.pop();
}

arr.push(data);
```

OR

```
arr[0] = data;
```

That will also work

Thanks